# How to create a header in Smart GWT

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

I need the simplest thing I ever asked on Stackoverflow: `<h2>`-like object to present as a header above some widget.

I can create `Label`, but it has no way of setting large font size as far as I could find out.

So to reiterate the question: I want an equivalent of `<h2>` that could be put into `VLayout`.

Comment: You can also ask GWT questions from GWT developers here: https://gitter.im/gwtproject/gwt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution for that:

```
    VerticalPanel vp = new VerticalPanel();
    Element h2 = DOM.createElement("h2");
    HTMLPanel widget = HTMLPanel.wrap(h2);
    vp.add(widget);
```